# SublimeText: Find where method/function is called/invoked/referenced?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I know you can press Ctrl + R to find the Defition/Declaration of the function but how do you go back. Say you have a function and you want to know where it was used.

You can do normal search like `name(` and then it shows up But.. if name is minified then searching `A(` is less helpful and sometimes there is space `A (` wont be matched.

Also i could write regex every time but that's tedious and unproductive.

Just like there is a way to find where was the function defined there should be a way to highlight and go through each invocation of that function.. so basically search functionality in revers.

Comment: What sublime text version are you using 3? Because it works for me

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by it works. what works? Ctrl+R..? Yea it works for me too when i have to find the definition of the function. I want to see where was a certain was called.

Comment: oh ok called I didn't know what you mean by used so I just read over it. that's interesting. Found this package but trying to figure out how to use it: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/WhoCalled%20Function%20Finder

Comment: i use vscode, it comes with this already built in and many other common sense things. especially good autocomplete, terminal, etc. plugins were fun, but didn't really enjoy treasure hunting

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>F</kbd>

Also, third-party packages are available for Sublime. Try [WhoCalled](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/WhoCalled%20Function%20Finder).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that Sublime Text cannot "go to usages". It is not an Intellisense-type IDE. It's not like working with NetBeans or Visual Studio, where it indexes all usages and function calls in the background and allows you to traverse them.

The best you can do is a simple text search (or regex), and limit the files searched by type or directory.

Or you can use a plugin from the Sublime Text community - though I've found such plugins to be non-functional or buggy, or not quite what you asked for.

The best option seems like what you've indicated you are already using - use a different IDE.